# jQuery init() function.

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Is there a way to force widgets to output jquery init() functions in one '$(document).ready()'?
It should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.style1').plugin1Init();
     $('.style2').plugin2Init();
     $('.style3').plugin3Init();
});
```

I'm asking because I'm trying to speed up my wordpress theme. I have several widgets which outputs jquery code in $(document).ready() functions.

Three '$(document).ready()' functions reduces page loading speed almost three times according to [Jquery speed test](http://jsperf.com/docready/3)

Example code on a page when I'm using 3 widgets:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.style1').plugin1Init();
});

$(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.style2').plugin2Init();
});

$(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.style3').plugin3Init();
});
```

Comment: Having multiple *document ready* blocks is not a problem at all. There is only a single event which will call all registered functions in a loop. If your page loads slowly it's due to something else.

Comment: _if_ you link to a test, make sure [you check the latest one](http://jsperf.com/docready/10)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `$(document).ready(function($) {` once

See:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.style1').plugin1Init();
    $('.style2').plugin2Init();
    $('.style3').plugin3Init();
});
```